# Is it possible to use other varibles to color a line when using ColorFunction?

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

I know that in `Plot` or `ListLinePlot` functions, we can color the line by specify the ColorFunction option, and then the line will be colored according to the variables such as the y coordinate. For example,

```
ListLinePlot[{{0, -0.5}, {0.5, 1}, {1, -1.0}},
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01]]
```

My question is whether it is possible to use the third variable to specify the color of the line, namely the $x$ and $y$ variables are just the coordinates and the value at this point is $z$. The background of my question is that I have obtained the solution $z$ at the line nodes $(x,y)$, and I want to use this value to color the connecting line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a list of `{x, y, z}` points, you could try this:

```
pts = Table[{x, x^2, 2 Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 4 \[Pi], 0.1 \[Pi]}];
Graphics[{
  AbsoluteThickness[3],
  Line[pts[[All, {1, 2}]], 
    VertexColors -> 
      ColorData["TemperatureMap"] /@ Rescale[pts[[All, 3]]]]
  },
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  Frame -> True
]
```

You can feed `Graphics` all of the same options as `ListLinePlot`, so you should be able to achieve whatever style you want.

[image: Image of a line with Temperature Map scaling.]